# Assign a target to a script programmatically in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, target

In the game I am trying to create, enemies are being spawned. The base enemy contains a script named "ShootableBox" in which the target is the "Player". However, when the clone enemies are created, the script does not have the "Player" target anymore and I want to assign them just like how they are being assigned in the Inspector.

Here is my spawn code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject enemy;
public Transform [] spawnPoints;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating ("SpawnEnemy", 5.0f, 5.0f);
}

void Update() {

}

public void SpawnEnemy() {
    int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);
    Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints [spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints [spawnPointIndex].rotation);
}
}
```

How can I assign them? I apologize I'm still new to this. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Give the Player Object a tag like "Player".  After the enemy is instantiated you can reference that instance's script and assign the target right there.

```
ShootableBox enemyScript = enemy.GetComponent<ShootableBox>();

GameObject player = GameObject.FindGameObjectByTag("Player");

enemyScript.target = player;
```

Comment: Hi. My ShootableBox script does not contain a definition for target. How can I assign that? I apologize and thank you.

Comment: You said it had target set to the player but the clones do not have it. Show us the ShootableBox script please.

Comment: Wanda, normally when you assign something in the inspector you have to create a `public GameObject enemy` like you've done in the spawn script. If you want The enemy script to contain a target for player you have to createt a field like this in that script for target, then set it with `target = GameObject.FindGameObjectByTag ("Player");` like Colby here did in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead assigning your player prefab into ShootableBox in **scene hierarchy**, assign it in **folder hierarchy (where you base enemy is located)**  or use colby answer.